# Adding 1 to the end (smallest digit) of a float, whatever length it is

Tags: python-2.7

I want to add 1 to the very end of a float, like this:
0.0735 + 0.0001 = 0.0736
But I'll get different lengths of floats, and for each I want to add 1 to the very end, like this:
0.000398 would have to be added to 0.000399 and 0.000000281 would have to be 0.000000282.

Also, if it's something like this: 0.0000280, I need to add it to the 0, not the 8. Which makes me believe that I have basically one problem: I need to find the first number after 0 and then count 2 more whatever it is, and add 1 to it (basically keeping 3 numbers, even if there's a 0 after)
Is there a way to do that?
edit: I tried this already `len(str(n))` but the problem is the zeros, as I don't have control over the length of the number, a number like this: 0.01 should be added to 0.0101 but if I have 0.0111 I want 0.0112. What I mean is, the program usually hides the zeroes, that's why I said I'd probably need to find the first non zero digit on it.

Comment: Will there always be 3 significant digits?

Comment: @yinnonsanders Yes, but in the 0.0000280 exemple it would give me 0.000028 instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10^floor(log10(n)) will get you a 1 digit at the same position as the first digit (e.g. 0.0001 for 0.000399), so add 0.01 times that:

```
n = 0.0735
n += 0.01 * 10 ** math.floor(math.log10(n))
```